# when i use Increment operator after else statment in a while loop its broke the whole program and it won't work

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, increment

when i run this code in the terminal i get a blank line that just wait for nothing
when i move the "i++;" under the "while(str[i]!='\0')" it works but thats not what i wanted , any help?

```
int main(){
    printf("hello kiddo");
    char str[20]="hel a awdaw dwa";
    int i=0;
    char *cleanstring;

    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if(str[i]==' '){
            continue;   
        }
        else{
            printf("%c",str[i]);    
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i dont know what wrong with this code

Comment: If the `continue;` is hit, the `i++` is skipped.

Comment: Instead, `if(str[i] != ' ') { printf("%c", str[i]); }`

Comment: There is no good reason not to use a `for` loop here. Replace the `while` with `for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {` and remove the `i++` at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Johnny Mopp's comment, notice the difference when adding the \n to your printf your program needs to flush the character and will not until the end of line, which as he says never happens since the loop gets stuck.

```
int main() {
  printf("hello kiddo");
  char str[20] = "hel a awdaw dwa";
  int i = 0;
  char * cleanstring;

  while (str[i] != '\0') {
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
      printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: no the problem was in the 'continue;' line it was skipping the 'i++;' and i did't know about that , thx to Jonny mopp

Answer (score -3):

i solved this problem editing the "if condition" like that

```
while(str[i]!='\0'){
        //if(str[i]==' '){
        //    continue;   
        //}
        //else{
        //   printf("%c",str[i]);    
        //}
        //i++;

        if(str[i]!=' '){
            strncat(cleanstring,&str[i],1);
        }           
        i++;

    }
```

the code was long for no reason and its better right now but , still wanna know why it didn't work in the first time.

Comment: Am I missing something? This looks identical to the code in the question that doesn't work.

Comment: The reason it didn't work was explained in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279579/when-i-use-increment-operator-after-else-statment-in-a-while-loop-its-broke-the#comment127696453_72279579). The `continue` skips everything else in the loop, including the `i++;`.

Comment: the pointer: `cleanstring` is a 'wild' pointer that does not (necessarily) point to memory that the application owns.  so saving characters where it points in memory results in undefined behavior